# How to minimize the zooming effect in the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a website and was using this slider for the website http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Lightweight-Background-Slideshow-Plugin-with-jQuery-CSS3-pureSlider.html ...but I'm unable to control the zooming speed of this slider..I tried various numbers for the animDuration:  8000 in the js file but it is not helping...Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please add a minimal, working and a reproducible code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the file pureslider.css change the values of the transition-duration property as you want.

```css
.stage .slide.on {
 transition-property: opacity, transform, z-index;
 transition-duration: 1000ms, 1000ms, 10ms;
 transition-function: linear;
 transition-delay: 0ms;
 transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 10;
}
```